# Can I power an ESP32 through the Vin pin?

Tags: power-supply, esp32

I can't find a clear answer on this through my searches, maybe someone here can help me.

Can I power my ESP32 through the Vin pin?

What is the best way to do it?

[image]

Comment: The ESP32 has no such pin. You must be using a module that contains an ESP32. Check the documentation of your module, or at least provide which specific module you have that contains an ESP32.

Comment: I wonder what the label "Vin" stands for. Maybe "voltage in". That sounds like a good place to put the voltage in, yes it does.

Comment: @Justme i just added a picture of the module. The reason i posting this here is because i could not find any documentation anywhere.

Comment: That would be the intended usage, yes, but you need to check the board documentation for the input range of the regulator used.  Pay attention to both minimum and maximum.  Or you could connect the USB Jack to a USB supply or host...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

V<sub>in</sub> on Arduinos, and on this kind of "compatible" ESP32 boards, is connected to a voltage regulator on the board, in this case the [AMS1117](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf), which is a linear regulator with a 3.3 V output.

As it is a linear regulator, I wouldn't put too high a voltage on the regulator's input, as it may run hot. It is a low-drop-out regulator, and should work properly with 5 V as input voltage.

You could also use USB to power the board, of course.

Comment: i'm going to use and external power supply of 5v to power the MCU and other components as well. thanks for your reply, it helped a lot

Comment: @nunocv
Hi. I've a similar issue. Have you succesfully powered the board by simply connect the external power source to Vin and GND?

Comment: @M4Biz yes it works great. As someone mention here the key is to use a good power source (stable) and even with that i used a capacitor right next to the Vin and GND pins. If i recall right i used a 47uF

Answer (score 2):

It totally depends on your development board.

You can check your connection with schematic. If the Low Drop-Out (LDO) regulator input is directly tied to V<sub>in</sub> then you can use this pin directly as the input. Most of the boards outputs are like that. I think your board has the connection and you can use this pin as voltage input.

If you use USB charging with AC electricity, I recommend to you use a capacitor between the V<sub>in</sub> and GND pins.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a dev similar board.

As @ocrdu mentioned, there is a power regulator on the dev kit board, but the ESP32 itself only uses 3.3v

I have been able to power mine a few ways:

1. via the microUSB port (obviously)
2. via 5v to the VIN pin on the board
3. via 3.3v to the 3v3 pin

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that sending 5V to the VIN pin on my NodeMCU-32S board worked fine.
I also read somewhere that simultaneously connecting both 5V via usb and 5V via VIN at the same time might be a bad idea so please keep that in mind.